# white spaces in url

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I'm trying to access a url with spaces:

```
url_string = "http://api.company.com/SendMessageXml.ashx?SendXML=<company><User><Username>username</Username><Password>passweord</Password></User><Content Type=sms>.."
with urllib.request.urlopen(url_string) as url:
    s = url.read()
```

The problem is with the space in "content type" separates
the string to two different blocks.

How can I send this request?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the space with %20 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib.parse, urllib.request

params = { "SendXML": "<company><User><Username>username</Username><Password>passweord</Password></User><Content Type=sms>.." }
url_string = "http://api.company.com/SendMessageXml.ashx?%s" % (urllib.parse.urlencode(params))
s = ""
with urllib.request.urlopen(url_string) as url:
    s = url.read()

print s
```

Comment: it gives me "Illegal XML" response from the server.

Comment: @user1641071 change `params["SendXML"]` to original xml data.

Comment: Now it works with this exmaple! my mistake. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys,

I found another (crazy but working) solution:

```
url_string.replace (" ","%20")
```

Comment: If you're already using urllib3, then you should use the functionality it provides. Otherwise you'll have to replace everything that needs to be encoded, for example the `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

```
import urllib.parse
query = urllib.parse.urlencode({
  "SendXML":
  "<company><User><Username>username</Username><Password>passweord</Password></User><Content Type=sms>.."
})
urllib.request.urlopen(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the other answers are either using python 2.x or urllib and the question is tagged for `urllib3`, here's a version that works with [`urllib3`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on python 3.x.

the `request` will encode the url for you. If you for some reason need to do this manually, you can find it in [`urllib3.request.urlencode`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#urllib3.request.RequestMethods.request_encode_url).

```
>>> params = {'SendXML': '<company><User><Username>username</Username><Password>passweord</Password></User><Content Type=sms>'}
>>> url = "http://api.company.com/SendMessageXml.ashx"
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> r = http.request('GET', url, params)
```